# Remove properties based on name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some object with assigned properties ( keys ) to that object , now I use the method `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` , to get an array with all properties assigned to that Object.

The problem is I want to find all properties that contains the string "item" , then eliminate it , not assigning null value to it , is this possible without using Regex ? something like jQuery `.contains()` ?

Comment: Loop through the keys compare the keyname to check for "item" if so `delete` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(name) {
    if(name.indexOf('item') >= 0) {
        delete obj[name];
    }
});
```

This is case sensitive.

Use `name.toLowerCase()` for case insensitive.

Comment: this is a clone of the previous answer but thanks anyway !

Comment: @ProllyGeek, other way around. I answer one minute before the other answer.

Comment: oh didn't notice , why did you vote for closure then ?!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic

Try with following code snippet to get the desired value from array and delete

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(name) {
    if(name.indexOf('item') >= 0) {
        delete obj[name];
    }
});
```

Hope this can be helpful.